# VSCode dbg attach local process to debug C dll which is used by C# dll

Tags: c#, c, debugging, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I'd like to debug the C DLL `quickfuncs.dll`, compiled with -g (debug symbols) by MinGW64, in VSCode. This DLL is used by C# DLL (also compiled with debug symbols), which is runned by:
`"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" exec "D:\Server\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Server.dll" Parameter1=test`

I've configured `launch.json` based on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/launch.md

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Attach to process",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "c:/msys2/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "targetArchitecture": "x64",
            "additionalSOLibSearchPath": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/win64/;d:\\Server\\src\\Server\\WorkingDirectory\\",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": false,
                }
            ],
            "logging": { 
                "trace": true, 
                "traceResponse": true
                },
        }
    ]
}
```

Afterer attaching the process, could'n set the brakpoint with this log:

```
C setBreakpoints: {"source":{"name":"api.c","path":"D:\\c_code\\quickfuncs\\api.c"},"lines":[246],"breakpoints":[{"line":246}],"sourceModified":false}
 R: {"success":true,"message":null,"request_seq":11,"command":"setBreakpoints","body":{"breakpoints":[{"id":3,"verified":true,"line":246,"message":null}]},"running":false,"refs":null,"seq":0,"type":"response"}
E breakpoint: {"reason":"changed","breakpoint":{"id":3,"verified":false,"line":246,"message":"Attempting to bind the breakpoint...."},"type":"breakpoint"}
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Why does the breakpoint isn't working?

Comment: It's in progress here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2452.

pieandcakes wrote:

> With MinGW you have to send Ctrl+C to the debuggee to pause. The pause
>   button doesn't work because we can't send **SIGINT** through `gdb`'s
>   MI protocol. The command we typically use is `-exec-interrupt` but
>   that doesn't work. The procedure (unfortunately) is:
>
> 1. Hit `pause` in the UI
> 2. Go to the debuggee and press `Ctrl+c`.
>
> At that point the debuggee should stop. It is only then that the
>   breakpoints bind.

This solution works for me. Many thanks.